# Angularjs : get style of selected option

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to get the style of an option when it is selected to set this style to the select (parent) element.

I can't get the style of the select option whn selected. Only it's value is available...

Is there a way to get that in Angular?
Please find code below, need some help.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">

 <select ng-model="element" ng-change="getElement(element)" ng-style="getSelectedStyle(color)">
     <option ng-repeat=option in options" ng-style="{'color' : option.color}">  //NG-STYLE
          {{option.value}}
     </option>
 </select>

</div>

(function(){

  app.controller('MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.element;
    $scope.getElement = function(item){
       console.log(item);
    };

    $scope.color = 'red';
    $scope.getSelectedStyle = function(){
       return { 'color' : $scope.color };
    };


    $scope.options = [

       {
          value : 'ezez',
          color : 'blue'
       }
    ];

  });  

})();
```

Comment: You have `getSelectStyle` function in your view, but your scope's function is called `getSelectedStyle`

Comment: This was just a typo...

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an object in your ng-style so try something like

```
ng-style="{'color': option.color}"
```

In your template you use `getSelectedStyle(color)` but in your controller you have

```
$scope.getSelectedStyle = function(){
   return { 'color' : $scope.color };
};
```

Where is your `$scope.color` i think in getSelectedStyle() you should use `$scope.element` and do this in your function.

```
$scope.getSelectedStyle = function(){
   return { 'color' : $scope.element.color };
};
```

Comment: option.color is not available in the parent element. The problem is to access the style, not displaying it

Answer (score 0):

Your markup would be

```
<select ng-model="element" ng-change="getElement(element)" ng-style="getSelectStyle(color)">
     <option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-style="{'color': option.color == element.color ? 'option.color': 'defaultColor' }">
          {{option.value}}
     </option>
 </select>
```